# php catch POST value

Tags: php, post

```
curl -d "id=1&name&age=12" http://localhost/post.php
```

i am having problem to output **name** because its empty

```
Array
(
    [id] => 1
    [age] => 12
)
```

how to get result as

```
Array
(
    [id] => 1
    [age] => 12
    [name] => 
)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
curl -d "id=1&name=&age=12" http://localhost/post.php
```

should do the trick

Comment: sometimes user will post id=1&name&age=12

Answer (score 1):

```
    $var  = 'id=1&name&age=12' ;

    $text = explode('&',$var);
                $text = array_flip($text);

                if(!isset($text['name=']))
                    {
                      $var = str_replace('name','name=',$var);
                    }
     echo $var ;
   /* Should Return  'id=1&name=&age=12' always
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
echo file_get_contents("php://input");
```

Normal parameters you can get with

```
parse_str(file_get_contents("php://input"), $_POST);
```

for name you have to parse it yourself.

```
$a = explode('$', file_get_contents("php://input"));
```

Answer (score 0):

If name, id and age are fixed parameters, you can use a default array and do an `array_merge()` like this:

```
<?php

$default = array('id' => '', 'name' => '', 'age' => '');
$variables = array_merge($default, $_POST);
```

Comment: maybe user will curl -d "id=1&name=&age=12&tt=2&uu=88&hh=&bb=/" http://localhost/post.php